# Sorting a result set in PHP by a variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This seems like a simple problem but I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Below, I have a results set coming back from a form. For the most part, everything works as expected. The last step is that I would like to sort my results by the variable $gbl_timestamp so that the most recent entry is first. Thoughts?

```
    <?php 
    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wrappers/code-s.wrp.php"); 
    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/php/mobile-switch.php"); 
    require_once("../tim/includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
    <?php
    // 2. Perform database query
    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM assessment_info ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    // Test if there was a query error
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed.");
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ol>
        <?php
            // 3. Use returned data (if any)
            while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                // output data from each row
        ?>
                <li><?php print "<strong>Timestamp:</strong>" . $gbl_timestamp?>        
                <br />
                <?php print "<strong>Department:</strong> ".       $results["department"] . "
                 <br /><strong>Participant</strong>: " . $results["participant"] . " <br /> <strong>Activity Performed:</strong> " . $results["activity"] . "
                 <br /><strong>Location:</strong> " . $results["location"] . " <br /><strong>Average number of Injuries:</strong> " . $results["recordable_injuries"] . " in the " . $results["recordable_injuries_timeframe"] . ""; ?></li>
      <?php
            }
        ?>
        </ol>

        <?php
          // 4. Release returned data
          mysqli_free_result($result);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
  // 5. Close database connection
  mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: nowhere do you actually give $gbl_timestamp a value, and since it's not given a value anywhere in your loop. there's no point in sorting by it - it'll have the same (null?) value everywhere anyways.

Comment: And what's the value of `$gbl_timestamp`?

Comment: @MarcB maybe the $gbl_timestamp has been defined in the connection.php or another file that's been included?

Comment: maybe, but either way, it never changes inside the loop, so it's pointless to sort by it.

Comment: @MarcB yes, I see your point, of course you don't sort by the variable, you sort by the row in the table that contains the timestamp information

Comment: *I have a results set coming back from a form.* No you don't. There's no form in the question, and the query doesn't use any parameters from a form.

Comment: Yes, I do @Barmar. The form lives on another page. Some background info here - as I said the form data is working (I'm able to see the results) and the gbl_timestamp variable is also showing as you'll see from `<?php print "<strong>Timestamp:</strong>" . $gbl_timestamp?>`. And yes as someone else pointed out this is defined on another page. I just was trying to get my list to sort by that variable, which looks like:

`//TIMESTAMP YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$gbl_timestamp = date("YmdHis");`

Comment: Ok I think I just figured this out. Instead of using a variable, I can use the sql timestamp function to automatically add the timestamp and then I sort by that column

Comment: @timr It's still not clear what you mean by "sort by that variable". You sort a list by something in the list, not a variable that's the same for every item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. I added a new column in the database and I'm using the built in timestamp field from phpMyAdmin. so now all I need to add to my query was:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM assessment_info ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1";
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use an order by clause with the variable, if it exists in the table.

Another solution is to put each `<li>` in an array with the variable as index and sort the array.